# How to efficiently custom flatten a map

Tags: go

So  based on the resourcesToCreate parameter passed I have to create them accordingly to create the flow

But now the problem is while assigning the funcInput the json is actually nested based on the flow it creates and attributes can be present anywhere so I cant harcode.

```
Example 
"config": {
    "type": "func1",
    "config": {
        "param1": "10",
        "param2": "10"
    },
    "connected": [
        {
            "type": "func3",
            "config": {
              "param1": "10",
              "param2": "10"
            },
            "connected": [
                {}
        },
    ],
}
```

So was thinking it I flatten it like this I can refer irrespective of the flow

```
{
"func1": {
        "param1": "10",
        "param2": "10"
    },
"func3" : {
        "param1": "10",
        "param2": "10"
    },
}
```

So the code currently fattens the json but having trouble getting the desired output

```
func Flatten(prefix string, src map[string]interface{}, dest map[string]interface{}) {
    if len(prefix) > 0 {
        prefix += "."
    }
    for k, v := range src {
        switch child := v.(type) {
        case map[string]interface{}:
            Flatten2(prefix+k, child, dest)
        case []interface{}:
            for i := 0; i < len(child); i++ {
                dest[prefix+k+"."+strconv.Itoa(i)] = child[i]
            }
        default:
            dest[prefix+k] = v
        }
    }
}
``
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flattening is more like extracting values. Generic way is not possible but to depend on the JSON keys like `type`, `properties` and `connected` to efficiently extract the `func` and `param` values. Your flatten function should be like:

```golang
func keyValuePairs(m interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    kvs := make(map[string]interface{})
    if reflect.ValueOf(m).Kind() == reflect.Map {
        mp, ok := m.(map[string]interface{})
        if ok {
            var key string
            var value interface{}
            for k, v := range mp {
                switch k {
                case "type":
                    key = v.(string)
                case "properties":
                    value = v
                case "connected":
                    if collection, ok := v.([]interface{}); ok {
                        for _, c := range collection {
                            for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(c) {
                                kvs[nk] = nv
                            }
                        }
                    }
                default:
                    for nk, nv := range keyValuePairs(v) {
                        kvs[nk] = nv
                    }
                }
            }
            if key != "" {
                kvs[key] = value
            }
        } else {
            for k, v := range m.(map[string]interface{}) {
                kvs[k] = v
            }
        }
    }
    return kvs
}
```

The same code with example inputs: [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/llIUjKB9N60)

For better understanding the code snippet, check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/VagueCoder/37086acb50919a95ef025e0f05c27b61) where I was actually flattening a JSON to very last key-value pairs.